Is it possible to replace ceiling fan chain without turning off the circuit breaker (it's an apartment building, not a house)?
I have a ceiling fan whose chain broke off when trying to turn off the fan. It was on the highest speed. Luckily, it has a switch for winter, summer, and OFF. I set it to OFF and the fan stopped. The light switch is controlled by a chain, as well. That chain is fine. The light switch is also controlled by a wall switch. Setting the wall switch for the fan light to OFF should open the circuit for the light. Keyword should.
It looks like the fan needs to be disassembled to replace the fan chain. There's nothing left to pull. It just broke off clean.
Now, normally, if this was in a house, you'd find the circuit breaker that controls wherever the fan is connected and turn it off. Unfortunately, this in an apartment. I don't have direct access to a circuit breaker. That's all handled by the building. I'd rather not have to pay an electrician to replace a 5 dollar part simply because asking the building to repeatedly turn on and off the circuit breaker as I try to fix the chain is probably not realistic. I'd have to ask them to turn it off once and I have no idea what else it would turn off. And then tell them to turn it on. If turning off the circuit breaker is an absolute must, then I may have to pay up to an electrician.
The internal fan switch should be fine. It's not a bad fan switch. Just the fan chain broke off. I'd like to keep the fan switch in place and just replace the fan chain.
With that said, is it possible to not fiddle with the circuit breaker and simply set the fan switch to OFF, make sure the chain for the light turns it off, and then set the wall switch for the light to OFF and that should be sufficient for replacing the fan chain without risking getting electrocuted?

It is possible, but you have to believe you are working with live power that can kill, usually something most DIYers and licensed electricians should not do.  This beside the fact that you are probably not allowed to do this by law.

There are two issues here:

Can you do this work?

In most places, you can't do actual electrical wiring work (replace switch, etc.) in an apartment building unless you are a licensed electrician. On the one hand, the fan is hardwired and therefore "part of the electrical system". On the other hand, you are trying to replace a simple mechanical part and the electrical issue is simply one of making sure it is safe to work around the exposed wiring of the fan. That's something you have to decide, possibly in consultation with your landlord.

Safety

If you knew beyond any reasonable doubt that the wall switch was on the hot wire and not the neutral wire then it would be perfectly safe to work on the internals of the fan with the light switch off and, for example, taped over to make sure nobody turned it on while you were working on it. The only exception would be actually taking the entire fan down from the ceiling because there could be a hot wire in the ceiling even if the hot wire to the fan is properly switched.
However, wiring is often done improperly. I have found hot/neutral reversed in a number of places in my house. I recently found a switched neutral on a light fixture - which is the kind of problem that could be fatal here if you worked without turning off the breaker.
The older a building is, the more likely it is to have problems, simply because more people, including some who may not have been licensed electricians, may have worked on things. Not having a breaker box in your apartment is an indication of age, though not necessarily of any actual problems.
There is no way to tell for sure whether the hot wire is switched vs. neutral wire switched except to actually go poking around the switch and/or the ceiling above the fan with testers. And that is not advisable in an apartment without access to the breaker.
Unfortunately, that means my recommendation is DO NOT WORK ON THIS WITHOUT TURNING OFF THE BREAKER because the risk, while small, is very much non-zero, and unlike some things, if there is a problem it can be fatal.
